# Solving for an angle in an $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle ($60^\circ$-$70^\circ$ variant)

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I cant solve this question for the life of me and this is some simple as heck geometry 101 problem. Now this would not be as bad but considering I'm in calculus 3 this seriously leaves a dent in my ego. This meme of a question is making me think its one of those millennial questions by someone at Clay that showed up on my class board to find Will Hunting or something. [image: Link to the question] Also can you be sure to include the steps. Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: This is a famous problem, it is very difficult in my opinion.

Comment: There is something wrong with the question

Comment: What is wrong @V.Chen?

Comment: Oh; nevermind.'

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HQc-54hQ8kw